# April 2014 update taken, bootup hangs at Stopping System V runlevel compatibility

Tags: 12.04, boot, system, lts, runlevel

I've seen other threads related to my current situation, but the solutions posted didn't help...

After accepting updates this morning, my system halts at "Stopping System V runlevel compatibility"

Here are the links I followed:

- [Stuck on Stopping System V runlevel compatibility](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184411/stuck-on-stopping-system-v-runlevel-compatibility)

  and

  [12.04: Kernel Update - Stopping System Runlevel V Compatibility](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399186/12-04-kernel-update-stopping-system-runlevel-v-compatibility)

Even after following the CHOWN commands as listed, and trying to step back one kernel version, same problem.. stuck on startup.

Unfortunately I don't know more of my version than 12.04 LTS

Your help and attention are greatly appreciated,

Paul

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but boot recovery shows my current version as 3.2.0-60 generic.